# Find missing and out-of-sequence records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**The schema:**

Simplified - a table listing ID numbers, their version and status:

```
CREATE TABLE archive
    ([id] int, [version] int, [status] varchar(1));

INSERT INTO archive
    ([id], [version], [status])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'A'),
    (1, 2, 'S'),
    (1, 3, 'T'),
    (1, 4, 'A'),
    (2, 2, 'T'),
    (2, 4, 'T'),
    (3, 1, 'A'),
    (3, 3, 'A');
```

**The problem:**

Some records are missing their full history (version).  All IDs should start with version 1 and version numbers should be continuous (unlike IDs 2 and 3 from the above schema).

**The desired output**

A listing of all IDs showing their existing versions as well as the "skipped" ones.  Based on the example below the output should look like:

```
id | ver | check
---+-----+------
  1|   1 |   1
  1|   2 |   2
  1|   3 |   3
  1|   4 |   4
  2| NULL|   1
  2|   2 |   2
  2| NULL|   3
  2|   4 |   4
  3|   1 |   1
  3| NULL|   2
  3|   3 |   3
```

**My efforts so far:**

The problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57664065/find-missing-records-from-sequence) but there is no fixed "Table2" as in the already answered question.  The number of versions for each record is not known.

So far I've came up with the following:

```
SELECT sub.id, sub.ver, sub.seq
FROM (
      SELECT CASE WHEN a.id IS NULL THEN b.id ELSE a.id END as 'id', b.version as 'ver', a.seq as 'seq'
      FROM (select *,
                   row_number() over (partition by id order by version asc) as seq
              from archive) a
      FULL OUTER JOIN archive b ON a.id=b.id AND a.seq=b.version) sub
ORDER BY sub.id, sub.ver, sub.seq
```

Which gets me almost there with the following output:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How refreshing to see such a well written question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is achievable using a `recursive cte.`

```
with cte as (
  select 1 as ctr, id, max(version) version from archive group by id
  union all 
  select ctr + 1, id, version from cte
  where ctr < version
)
select t1.id, t2.version, ctr as [check] from cte t1
left join archive t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t1.ctr = t2.version
order by t1.id, t1.ctr;
```

see [dbfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cf492b/12)

Comment: Thank you.  Very nice and elegant.  Worked great.  Just FYI, I got "The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion" error but that was easily fixed with a quick Google.

Comment: @MichalRosa, yes, sql server requires to set max recursion, default is 100

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version that uses a Numbers Table and doesn't suffer from any CTE recursion boundaries. The numbers table can support much a much greater range of values than you can get from a recursive CTE.

```
-- Create a numbers table. This table can be generated each time 
-- or stored in a static table. Numbers tables are wonderful things.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Numbers
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n1.[object_id]) AS [number]
INTO
    #Numbers
FROM
    [sys].[objects] AS n1
    ,[sys].[objects] AS n2

-- Calculate the "range" of version numbers for each [id]
;WITH [range]
AS
(
    SELECT
        [id]
        ,1 AS [min_version]
        ,MAX([version]) AS [max_version]
    FROM
        [archive] AS a
    GROUP BY
        [id]
), [expected]
AS
(
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        a.[id]
        ,n.[number]
    FROM
        #Numbers AS n
        INNER JOIN [range] AS a
            ON n.number BETWEEN a.[min_version] AND a.[max_version]
)
SELECT
    e.[id]
    ,a.[version] AS [ver]
    ,e.[number] AS [check]
FROM
    [expected] AS e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [archive] AS a
        ON e.[id] = a.[id]
        AND e.[number] = a.[version]
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works great as well and avoiding recursion has its advantages but for the simplicity and elegance I prefer the first solution (in the actual database there are only a few records with over 100 versions so the query does not suffer from any performance issues).  I will keep your solution in my "recipe book".